# How to write data to InfluxDB with ESP8266 / NodeMCU over Internet & HTTPS?

Tags: https, esp8266, influxdb, arduino-esp8266

I want to securely send data to my InfluxDB over the Internet using a NodeMCU MCU and a self signed cert.

I found this library that seems to accomplish exactly this but get compile errors, more below -> https://medium.com/@teebr/iot-with-an-esp32-influxdb-and-grafana-54abc9575fb2

This library seems to only use HTTP -> Am i mistaken?
https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/esp8266-influxdb

Using the example from the 1st library above from TEEBR, i get this error compiling - Any suggestions on how to fix?  Will this run on my NodeMCU?

Thanks

C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Influx-Arduino-master\InfluxArduino.cpp:1:24: fatal error: HTTPClient.h: No such file or directory

#include 
                        ^
compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

My code

```
//https://medium.com/@teebr/iot-with-an-esp32-influxdb-and-grafana-54abc9575fb2
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "InfluxArduino.hpp"
#include "InfluxCert.hpp"

InfluxArduino influx;


//connection/ database stuff that needs configuring
char WIFI_NAME[] = "ssid";
const char WIFI_PASS[] = "password!";
const char INFLUX_DATABASE[] = "db_name";
const char INFLUX_IP[] = "10.10.101.101";
const char INFLUX_USER[] = "db_name"; //username if authorization is enabled.
const char INFLUX_PASS[] = "Password"; //password for if authorization is enabled.
const char INFLUX_MEASUREMENT[] = "FromESP8266"; //measurement name for the database. (in practice, you can use several, this example just uses the one)


unsigned long DELAY_TIME_US = 5 * 1000 * 1000; //how frequently to send data, in microseconds
unsigned long count = 0; //a variable that we gradually increase in the loop

void setup()
{   
    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.begin(WIFI_NAME, WIFI_PASS);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("WiFi connected!");
    influx.configure(INFLUX_DATABASE,INFLUX_IP); //third argument (port number) defaults to 8086
    influx.authorize(INFLUX_USER,INFLUX_PASS); //if you have set the Influxdb .conf variable auth-enabled to true, uncomment this
    influx.addCertificate(ROOT_CERT); //uncomment if you have generated a CA cert and copied it into InfluxCert.hpp
    Serial.print("Using HTTPS: ");
    Serial.println(influx.isSecure()); //will be true if you've added the InfluxCert.hpp file.
} 

void loop()
{   
    unsigned long startTime = micros(); //used for timing when to send data next.

    //update our field variables
    float dummy = ((float)random(0, 1000)) / 1000.0;
    count++;

    //write our variables.
    char tags[32];
    char fields[32];

    sprintf(tags,"new_tag=Yes"); //write a tag called new_tag
    sprintf(fields,"count=%d,random_var=%0.3f",count,dummy); //write two fields: count and random_var
    bool writeSuccessful = influx.write(INFLUX_MEASUREMENT,tags,fields);
    if(!writeSuccessful)
    {
        Serial.print("error: ");
        Serial.println(influx.getResponse());
    }

    while ((micros() - startTime) < DELAY_TIME_US)
    {
      //wait until it's time for next reading. Consider using a low power mode if this will be a while.
    }
}
```

Long time reader, first time poster - Thanks for all the help in the past!